# Compressing cyclic data?

Tags: data-structures, compression

Suppose I have, e.g., polygon vertices stored in a list. Any rotation of the list is functionally equivalent (in this case, because the ordering of vertices in an arbitrary polygon is significant, but what you choose as the starting point is not). Ergo, there are extra bits of information in the list representation, proportional to the log of the number of items in the list.

Is there a way to compress such data to eliminate the extra bits encoding a particular rotation? If so, is there a *generic* algorithm / data structure for it, or will it depend on the specific type of the data elements (numbers, tuples of numbers for coordinates, arbitrary objects, etc.)?

Comment: Hardly seems even worth thinking about. Even if you had four billion vertices, the most you could save is four bytes off the entire representation.

Comment: @MarkAdler It may not be particularly practical, but that doesn't mean it isn't *interesting*.